# Is there a more readable or Pythonic way to format a Decimal to 2 places?

Tags: python, decimal, rounding

What the heck is going on with the syntax to fix a Decimal to two places?

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> num = Decimal('1.0')
>>> num.quantize(Decimal(10) ** -2) # seriously?!
Decimal('1.00')
```

Is there a better way that doesn't look so esoteric at a glance? 'Quantizing a decimal' sounds like technobabble from an episode of Star Trek!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use string formatting:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> num = Decimal('1.0')
>>> format(num, '.2f')
'1.00'
```

The [`format()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format) applies string formatting to values. `Decimal()` objects can be formatted like floating point values.

You can also use this to interpolate the formatted decimal value is a larger string:

```
>>> 'Value of num: {:.2f}'.format(num)
'Value of num: 1.00'
```

See the [format string syntax documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax).

Unless you know exactly what you are doing, expanding the number of significant digits through quantisation is not the way to go; quantisation is the privy of accountancy packages and normally has the aim to round results to *fewer* significant digits instead.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand `quantize()` even after reading the docs.  Is that used just to set the precision?

Comment: No, it is used to round of results to match the exponent of another value and is primarily useful in accounting, I think.

Comment: @Mark: Yes, `Decimal.__format__()` is called, and that method supports the same instructions as float values do.

Answer (score 2):

Quantize is used to set the number of places that are actually held internally within the value, before it is converted to a string. As Martijn points out this is usually done to *reduce* the number of digits via rounding, but it works just as well going the other way. By specifying the target as a decimal number rather than a number of places, you can make two values match without knowing specifically how many places are in them.

It looks a little less esoteric if you use a decimal value directly instead of trying to calculate it:

```
num.quantize(Decimal('0.01'))
```

You can set up some constants to hide the complexity:

```
places = [Decimal('0.1') ** n for n in range(16)]

num.quantize(places[2])
```