# Decimal rounding with .quantize() does not use original context

Tags: python, python-2.7, decimal, rounding

If I do the following, I would expect `0.005` to be rounded up to `0.01` instead of down to `0.00` because rounding was set to *ROUND_HALF_UP*.

```
>>> import decimal
>>> currency = decimal.Context(rounding=decimal.ROUND_HALF_UP)
>>> cents = decimal.Decimal('0.00')
>>> amount = currency.create_decimal('0.005')
>>> amount
Decimal('0.005')
>>> amount.quantize(cents)
Decimal('0.00')
```

But if I pass *currency* to `quantize()`, it rounds properly:

```
>>> amount.quantize(cents, context=currency)
Decimal('0.01')
```

Why does *amount* (which was created from the *currency* context) not round using the *currency* context?

NOTE: This question is not asking *how* to round to 2 decimal places. I am merely using that as an example. I would like to know *why* a `Decimal` created from a `Context` does not use that same `Context` when quantizing/rounding.

Comment: Are you sure you want `quantize`? It's not for rounding, but has some specific function in accounting. If you're just looking for rounding, either use the math rounding function or string formatting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a more readable or Pythonic way to format a Decimal to 2 places?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18834897/is-there-a-more-readable-or-pythonic-way-to-format-a-decimal-to-2-places)

Comment: I asked a similar question (linked above) when I was first picking up Python because I had a similar confusion to yours. Quantize has some special function I still don't quite understand and is apparently used in accounting. The normal methods for rounding decimals are what I described above.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist I don't think this is a duplicate. I'm not asking *how* to round to 2 decimal places. I'm was simply using that as an example. I'm more wondering *why* my example didn't work.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist This is *not* a duplicate of your question. You ask how to format a Decimal object. This asks why creating a Decimal from a context does not use the context.

Comment: @That1Guy Then don't vote for it. To me it sounds like an XY problem because this doesn't appear to be the right usage for `quantize`.

Comment: @That1Guy Sorry if that comment sounded rude or snippy. I only meant I don't think there's any harm linking the dupe if it's "wrong", as long as it doesn't get closed as a dupe incorrectly.

Comment: `amount` has no knowledge of the context it's created in: it's just a `Decimal` object (with some digits, a sign, and an exponent). If you want to operate in a particular context, you typically need to *set* that context.

Comment: @cpburnz: you need to set the context, as shown in my answer.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist No harm done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Decimal objects do not retain the context they were created from. Decimal operations that use a specific context, such as `Context.create_decimal` or `Decimal.quantize` with a context argument, only override the global context for that one operation; further operations on the resulting Decimal are done with the global context.

If you want to have all operations use `ROUND_HALF_UP`, you can set the global context:

```
decimal.setcontext(currency)
```

but if you want to mix contexts, you'll have to provide a context explicitly for every operation that needs a context other than the global context.

Comment: When you say "*override*" do you mean the global context is actually overwritten using assignment and then after the operation is done, reset to its original value, or does the context passed as a parameter merely "shadow" the global context? I'm asking from an efficiency standpoint. So suppose you want to use `ROUND_DOWN` for a large amount of numbers. Would setting the global context once instead of using quantize passing a context / rounding setting for every number be actually more efficient?

Comment: @Keiwan: The global context is not affected. As for efficiency, I have no idea.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the context using `decimal.setcontext()` or pass it to `quantize()` function as a keyword argument to work properly.

```
>>> import decimal
>>> currency = decimal.Context(rounding=decimal.ROUND_HALF_UP)
>>> decimal.setcontext(currency) # setting the context
>>> cents = decimal.Decimal('0.00')
>>> amount = currency.create_decimal('0.005')
>>> amount.quantize(cents)
Decimal('0.01')
```

Setting the context globally using `decimal.getcontext().rounding = decimal.ROUND_HALF_UP` works fine as well, but then it will be use for all future operations with any `Decimal`.

```
>>> import decimal
>>> decimal.getcontext().rounding = decimal.ROUND_HALF_UP
>>> cents = decimal.Decimal('0.00')
>>> amount = decimal.Decimal('0.005')
>>> amount.quantize(cents)
Decimal('0.01')
```

Comment: The questioner already knows that. The question is not about how to get `quantize` to use the context, but why `quantize` does not already use the context.

Comment: @user2357112: see my updated answer. Setting the context using `decimal.setcontext()` or `decimal.getcontext().rounding = decimal.ROUND_HALF_UP` works just fine.